# remove list items added via .append by click event on separate element

Tags: jquery, ios, click, append, cordova

I have the following html:

```
<div id="info">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <h1 class="popup-title"></h1>
        <a href="#map" class="back">Map</a>

    </div>

    <div class="categories rounded">
        <div class="column-one list-title">
            <h3>Categories</h3>

        </div>

        <div class="column-two list-items cats">
            <ul>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

With this jquery to fill the UL:

```
google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function () {
    for ( var i = 0; i < places.length; i++ ) {
        for ( var a = 0; a < places[i].categories.length; a++ ) {
            $( '#info .cats ul' ).append( '<li>' + places[i].categories[a] + '</li>' );
        }
    }
});
```

When the `a` tag with class `.back` is clicked I want the appended list items removed.

```
$( '.back' ).on( 'click', function () {
     $( '#info .cats ul' ).html( '' );
} );
```

unfortunately the list items are not removed and new list items just keep being added to the old ones. I have also tried:

```
$('#info .cats ul li').remove();
```

EDIT: For additional info - this is running fine in the browser now that I've checked it. The code does not clear the 'li' items in phonegap/cordova on ios using jqtouch. This may be a deeper issue with the platforms interacting. Is there perhaps some alternative code solution for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/DgqMh/. Is the click event being fired at all? Have you tried to put an `alert` or a `console.log` within it?

Comment: Thanks Joao, your right. The code works in browser. I didn't realize I would have issues considering the platform it's used on.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="info">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <h1 class="popup-title"></h1>
        <a href="#map" class="back">Map</a>
    </div>

    <div class="categories rounded">
        <div class="column-one list-title">
            <h3>Categories</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="column-two list-items cats"><ul></ul></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var $list = $( '#info .cats ul' );

google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function () {
    for ( var i = 0; i < places.length; i++ ) {
       for ( var a = 0; a < places[i].categories.length; a++ ) {
          $list.append( '<li>' + places[i].categories[a] + '</li>' );
       }
   }
});


$('.back').on( 'click' , function ( event ) {
     $list.empty();
     return false; //prevent the default anchor link action
});
```

You need to prevent the default action of the anchor link. Also cache the selector so that you dont have to query the DOM each time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but the best practices of jQuery append is using a string.

e.g.

```
var ulList = '';
    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function () {
        for ( var i = 0; i < places.length; i++ ) {
           for ( var a = 0; a < places[i].categories.length; a++ ) {
              ulList += '<li>' + places[i].categories[a] + '</li>';
//$list.append( '<li>' + places[i].categories[a] + '</li>' );
           }
       }
$list.append(ulList);
ulList = null;
    });
```